# got an error while connecting MySQL to Django as backend database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django, backend

In order to connect MySQL as Backend Language for Django I have made some changes in **settings.py** and I have given the changed code below

```
    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'django',
            'PASSWORD':'2684',
            'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
            'PORT':'3306',
            'USER':'root'
        }
    }
```

after saving it and while I execute  the command

`python manage.py makemigrations`

I got an Error mentioned

```
E:\Python\sample_django\root>python manage.py makemigrations
C:\Users\2684j\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py:105: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': (1193, "Unknown system variable 'default_storage_engine'")
  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

**My database Details given below**

**database Name : django**

**MySQL password : 2684**

**Port : 3306**

**Host : localhost**

**User : root**

Answer (score 1):

The probable reason for `RunTimeError` is the MySQL version. If your MySQL version is below 5.5, then variable name should be `storage_engine` while if it is above 5.7 it should be `default_storage_engine`.
Can you please let us know the MySQL version you are using?
You can also try adding the below `OPTIONS` structure in your settings.py `DATABASES` field:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'PASSWORD':'2684',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'USER':'root',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "init_command": "SET default_storage_engine=<DB name>",
        },
    }
}
```

The variable should be `storage_engine` if MySQL version<5.5 and `default_storage_engine` if MySQL version>5.7

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py makemigrations` only packages up your model changes into individual migration files. Since, you didn't make any further changes in your models, it says "No changes detected".

So, after you run `makemigrations`, you need to run `python manage.py migrate` to apply these to your database.

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#the-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Use First

> Python manage.py makemigrations

then

> Python manage.py migrate

All your problems will gone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your MySQL Version?

The name of the variable containing the "`default_storage_engine`" was changed from version 5.5 to 5.7

Before 5.5, there was only "`storage_engine`". Starting with 5.5, one could use both "`storage_engine`" and "`default_storage_engine`" and now above 5.7 only "`default_storage_engine`" is accepted.